# (PHP) file_get_contents - Contents url after questionmark?

Tags: php, curl

First of all, i'm new to PHP. I've got the following code-snippet and it works pretty well.

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
preg_match_all( '|<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i',$html, $matches ); 


foreach ($matches[1] as $match) { 
    echo '<img src="' . $match . '" />';
}
?>
```

Now i want to add the  file_get_contents url after a questionmark in the filename like:

```
http://www.example.com/getfile.php?http://www.url.com/images/
```

How to do this? Is this cURL?

Comment: Can you share the content on which you are applying `preg_match_all`?

Comment: no - you should add a url param as ?url=http://etc. etc. then you can acccess with $_GET['url'] to use for cURL and file_get_contents

Comment: I can't figure out what you have in mind. Is `http://www.example.com/getfile.php?http://www.url.com/images/` a real location? Can you open it in your web browser?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Thank you very much! See my edit for the solution :)

Comment: Please don't post solutions inside questions. Post solutions as solutions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, i just want to strip every image from a website. 
ie: http://www.mywebsite.com/getfile.php?url=http://www.msn.com

Comment: Please be warned that you are at *serious* risk for XSS. A malicious user could create a link such as `http://example.com/getfile.php?url=http://evilsite.com/hax`, which would contain carefully crafted code to inject whatever they want into your page.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks for pointing out. Seems like it isn't the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

Changing:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

to

```
$html = file_get_contents($_GET["url"]);
```

works! :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Perhaps not the best solution eh? ;)

Comment: I'm still not fully sure of what the problem is. Do you want to write an online service to scrape pictures from arbitrary web sites?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes :) Just for personal use.

Comment: Well you added a feature so your local filesystem could be scraped aswell. :)